# delay before running javascript code

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to run a piece of code after first completing jquery `hide` function but the code run before waiting to completely hide the elements.

This is the code:

```
$('p').hide(1000);
$('.menu-link').each(function(n, e){

   var len = $(e).next('ul').find('a').length;
   $(e).find('div').text(len);

});
```

How can I run this code after completing `hide()` function that is complete in 1000 ms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**Call back**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-hide-speed.htm) to hide event

```
$('p').hide(1000, function () {
    $('.menu-link').each(function (n, e) {

        var len = $(e).next('ul').find('a').length;
        $(e).find('div').text(len);

    });
});
```

## [Demo Callback](http://jsfiddle.net/MSa2u/)

Answer (score 0):

Write as callback:

```
$('p').hide(1000, function() {
  $('.menu-link').each(function(n, e){
    var len = $(e).next('ul').find('a').length;
    $(e).find('div').text(len);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
setTimeout(function(){  }, 1500);
```

or use callback!!

```
$('element').hide("1000", function() { ... });
```